# remove measurement

Tags: measurement

I love the new measure tool, but seems I have a measurement that just will not delete.
When I delete it (either with the delete button or with X) it seems to vanish only to reappear shortly later again.

How do you delete/remove a measurement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and already [reported](https://developer.blender.org/T63250) to the developers.